# What is the genre of this music I've created with FruityLoops?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I've created a little music with [FruityLoops](https://www.image-line.com/flstudio/) and I would like to know what genre it is.

My brother said that is Eurodance. I said that is Trance. Who is right?

---

Url of music : http://picosong.com/HPJJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been deejaying since 1984 and one thing is certain, categorizing styles is one difficult task especially in the EDM scene. So many things to consider and at the end the song creator can say you are way off, my style is Disco House with Persian folk infusion. lol but seriously, you know what I mean?

Soooo with that. We can use a deduction method to address the song at hand. 
**Eurodance term faded out in the 90s and is mostly referred to progressive house**. This song has neither the hard hitting kick to make it house or speed to consider it progressive house at that.

Trance....again this is a little on the slow side and misses a key element in making it trance..

When you think of someone being hypnotized, i think of a clock moving back and forth and as you follow it you start to fall into a state of trance.

Normally it is done with a sound that continues throughout the beat that sways side to side up and down, heavy in presence but soft in blending.

A great example to me is Tiesto - Adagio For Strings

Freakin base pumpin, beat hitting, strings melodically placing one in a trance.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0PV_S4m6Ig

So to me with this clip both are right and wrong and for me it is basically a generic non risky slow house beat.

Hope that helps and makes sense.

Comment: So, it is House ?

Comment: Yes, it is house music :)